# Відповідник human readable

Tags: переклад, from-english, відповідник

З огляду на [усталені переклади системи Drupal](https://localize.drupal.org/node/186) словосполучення, *human readable* перекладається як *легке для читання* , що є не зовсім відповідним до антоніму *machine name* і часом заважає зрозуміти, що мається на увазі.

Який відповідник можна використати в даному випадку?

Comment: Можете навести приклад в контексті? (Наприклад, може, вистачить просто [«розбірливий» (2)](http://sum.in.ua/s/rozbirlyvyj).)

Comment: На правах особистої словотворчості: «людинопридатний», «машинопридатний». Не підтверджено мовною практикою.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

От що кажуть [Ольга Кочерга](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0_%D0%9E%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B3%D0%B0_%D0%94%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0) і [Володимир Пілецький](http://philology.lnu.edu.ua/employee/piletskyj-volodymyr) у своїй статті [Процесові прикметники в українській мові](http://tc.terminology.lp.edu.ua/TK_Wisnyk676/TK_wisnyk676_kocherha_pilec'kyj.htm):

> Завважимо також, що українська мова поступово усуває скальковані з
>   англійської через посередництво російської мови прикметники на
>   позначення пасивної здатности з суфіксом -**абельн**-: *(не)читабельний,
>   (не)презентабельний, (не)транспортабельний, (не)комунікабельний* тощо.
>   Натомість вона відновлює (чи творить наново) слова з такою самою
>   функцією за допомогою українських словотворчих суфіксів: *(не)читний,
>   (не)презентовний, (не)транспортовний, (не)комуніковний* тощо. Варто
>   звернути увагу на питомі чи запозичені основи таких слів. Правила
>   дериваційної граматики української мови твердять, що питома основа
>   притягує питомі суфікси, а іншомовна — іншомовні. Гібриди, як правило,
>   набувають експресивно-оцінного забарвлення. Отже, запозичені основи
>   транспортабель-, операбель-, комунікабель- та інші вже припасовано до
>   граматичної системи української мови за допомогою суфікса -**н**-. У такий
>   спосіб відбулося їх засвоєння. Чи дійсно кращі від цих утворень
>   гібриди на зразок комуніковний, покаже їх конкурування у мовній
>   практиці. Можливо, свою нішу займуть обидва варіанти.

Отже, `readable` краще перекласти як `читний`, що і вимовляти, і писати зручніше. А `легкий для читання` можна подати як `легкочитний`.

**РЕД:**
Виявляється можливі відповіді доступні на у [статті на r2u](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=readable&highlight=on), наприклад,

- human-readable = людиносприйня́тна, сприйня́тна для люди́ни
- machine-readable = машино(з)чи́тна, опрацьо́вна

І варіанти для readable - прочитний, розбірливий, читабельний, читомий.

Comment: Але ж "readable" та "human readable" це різні речі (контекст другого значно вужчий).

Comment: @s0nata В іншій відповіді пан bytebuster запропонував відмовитись від частини *human*, я запропонував такий варіант, хоча дійсно, переклад із *human* був би доречнішим.

Comment: @s0nata а варіанти *машиночитний* і *людиночитний* я не наважився запропонувати, через *людиноненависницький*, який якби ненавидить людину, а не людина когось.

Comment: хм, гарне зауваження щодо "людиноненависницький". А як щодо "рукописний" - "писаний рукою"?

Comment: 'читний' - звучить добре )

Answer (score 8):

СУМ пропонує варіант [*читабельний*](http://sum.in.ua/s/chytabeljnyj) — який легко читається, має великий попит серед читачів; ходовий.

> *Я майже цілий тиждень правив цей матеріал, приводив його до **читабельного** вигляду. Друкуємо...* — Павло Автомонов, В. Кошик, 1954, 117
>
> *Є книжки цілком пристойні — грамотні й **читабельні** — про які одначе не хочеться сказати й слова, доброго чи поганого.. їх зміст живе тільки разом із шрифтом, яким вони надруковані, і — прочитані — вони забуваються з легким серцем* — Юрій Смолич, VI, 1959, 177

Особиста думка — суфікс `-абельн-` цілком годиться для постійного вживання у подібних випадках, і не лише для слова *readable*.

Стосовно частини *human* — вважаю (особиста думка), що його можна пропускати.

Тобто, у випадку дихотомії *machine name* vs. *human-readable*, це буде *машинна назва* і *читабельна назва*, відповідно.

Comment: Завжди вважав читабельний та інші подібні словоутворення калькою з російської мови, хоча такий варіант особисто мені подобається.