# Як правильно перекласти trainable на українську?

Tags: переклад, from-english

В контексті  - Trainable weights are the weights that will be learnt during the training process.

Бажано  одним словом. Я поки що вживаю  *научуваний*  але може є щось краще.

Comment: пов'язані [1](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/346/%d0%92%d1%96%d0%b4%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%96%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba-human-readable), [2](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/5835/%d0%af%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b7-%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%96%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%97-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8b%d0%b9), [3](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/2918)

Answer (score 3):

[Мейнарович і Кратко ("Англійсько-український словник з математики та інформатики" 2010)](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=trainable&dicts=2) пропонують:

> trainable = ['treɪnəbl] трено́вний, сприйня́тливий до навча́ння

Answer (score 2):

Тут допоможе [таке правило](https://r2u.org.ua/node/162):

> Почнімо із прикметників, що вказують на здатність бути підданим певній
>   дії (тобто пасивну здатність).
>
> Згадані прикметники найчастіше
>   утворюємо від префіксових перехідних дієслів, додаючи суфікс ***-н-*** до
>   дієслівного твірної основи й водночас відтинаючи від неї суфікси ***-и-,
>   -а-, -і-, -ну-*** : *змін-и-ти/змін-н-ий, передбач-и-ти/ передбач-н-ий, згин-а-ти/згин-н-ий, розв’яз-а-ти/розв’яз-н-ий, розгад-а-ти/
>   розгад-н-ий, вигой‑і‑ти/вигой-н-ий, стис-ну-ти/стис‑н‑ий.*
>
> Якщо твірна
>   дієслівна основа містить у своєму складі суфікс ***-ва-***, то від нього
>   відтинаємо кінцевий голосний: *розли-ва- -ти/розли-в-ний, зли-ва-
>   ти/зли-в-н-ий, розсу-ва -ти/ розсу‑в‑ний.*

Отже, **треновний**.

Щодо *научуваний*:

> Віддієслівні прикметники з кінцевим ***-овн***(ий) та пасивні дієприкметники минулого часу в двослівних найменуваннях об’єктів дії різняться семантично: *нехтовний член* — це той, що його можна викинути будь-коли, а *нехтуваний член* — це той, що ми його викидаємо у певний момент виконання дії;

Тому, мабуть, буде **научовний**, але тут я не певен.

Answer (score -3):

Можливо "витреновувальний" або "треновний".

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Наші критерії якості дещо відрізняються від того, що можна побачити на мовних форумах і блоґах. Необґрунтовані відповіді базуються лише на думці їхнього автора і тому викликають хвилю диспутів і заперечень. А якісні відповіді ґрунтуються на якісних джерелах: словниках, поважних сайтах тощо

Comment: Будь ласка, перегляньте сторінки [tour](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/tour), [How to Answer](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) а також [«Якими мають бути гарні відповіді»](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/%d0%a5%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d1%88%d1%96-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8f-%d1%96-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d1%88%d1%96-%d0%b2%d1%96%d0%b4%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%96%d0%b4%d1%96-good-questions-and-good-answers). Ви завжди можете виправити відповідь, зробивши її більш аргументованою.

Comment: _Треновний_ уже згадує інша відповідь. _Витреновувальний_ — це нова ідея, але чи Ви зможете десь знайти приклади вживання?